# Adwords API - AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED - Python

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm trying to use the Google Adwords Test API. I'm trying to connect to the Google Adwords API, but I keep getting the following error:

```
googleads.errors.GoogleAdsServerFault: [InternalApiError.UNEXPECTED_INTERNAL_API_ERROR @ com.google.ads.api.services.common.error.InternalApiError.<init>(InternalApiErro]
```

I've made a Google Adwords Production Account in order to get the developer API key. I've then made a Google Adwords Manager Test account and managed to get a Oauth Client id, and Secret Id. I then used the [Google Oauth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to get the refresh token. My google_adwords.yaml file now looks something like this:

```
# AdWordsClient configurations
adwords:
  #############################################################################
  # Required Fields                                                           #
  #############################################################################
  developer_token: **DEVELOPER TOKEN FROM PRODUCTION ACCOUNT PASTED HERE**
  #############################################################################
  # Optional Fields                                                           #
  #############################################################################
  client_customer_id: **CLIENT CUSTOMER ID FROM MANAGER TEST ACCOUNT PASTED HERE** 
  # user_agent: INSERT_USER_AGENT_HERE
  # partial_failure: True
  # validate_only: True
  #############################################################################
  # OAuth2 Configuration                                                      #
  # Below you may provide credentials for either the installed application or #
  # service account flows. Remove or comment the lines for the flow you're    #
  # not using.                                                                #
  #############################################################################
  # The following values configure the client for the installed application
  # flow.
  client_id: **CLIENT ID FROM MANAGER TEST ACCOUNT PASTED HERE** 
  client_secret: **CLIENT CUSTOMER SECRET FROM MANAGER TEST ACCOUNT PASTED HERE** 
  refresh_token: **REFRESH TOKEN FROM OAUTH PLAYGROUND ON BEHALF OF MANAGER TEST ACCOUNT PASTED HERE** 
  # The following values configure the client for the service account flow.
  # path_to_private_key_file: INSERT_PATH_TO_JSON_KEY_FILE_HERE
  # delegated_account: INSERT_DOMAIN_WIDE_DELEGATION_ACCOUNT
  #############################################################################
  # ReportDownloader Headers                                                  #
  # Below you may specify boolean values for optional headers that will be    #
  # applied to all requests made by the ReportDownloader utility by default.  #
  #############################################################################
  # report_downloader_headers:
    # skip_report_header: False
    # skip_column_header: False
    # skip_report_summary: False
    # use_raw_enum_values: False
```

My Python code looks something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from googleads import adwords

adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage('C:\Python36\google_adwords.yaml')
ad_group_service = adwords_client.GetService('TargetingIdeaService', version='v201802')

selector = {
    'ideaType': 'KEYWORD',
    'requestType': 'IDEAS'
}
page = ad_group_service.get(selector)

print (page)
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? I reckon there is something wrong with my YAML file, but can't quite place what it may be. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my issue. I got my client_customer_id wrong. I was using the id from my test manager account, but this is incorrect. You need to MAKE a new test client adwords account INSIDE your test manager account:

[image]

After I clicked on that button, I was able to link the test client to my MCC Account (the account that has my test developer token) with the 'Invite users to this account' section:

[image]

Now I have linked my test account and my MCC Account.

I then pasted my test client adwords account id (xxx-xxx-xxxx) into the 'client_customer_id' section of my YAML file. I ran my script and found that I had successfully connected to the API!

Comment: Do you know how to get it programmatically? Like if someone gives you their credentials, can I use their three credentials to pull in the client_customer_id so I can execute the code samples?